# Centering does not work within minipage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

I cannot place my plot centered on the page. I tried the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=5in]{plot1.pdf}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=5in]{plot2.pdf}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=5in]{plot3.pdf}
\end{minipage}
\caption{xxx} 
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

As one can recognize, the plot is not centered. Waht should I do to get it centered?

Comment: Remove the minipages.

Comment: How should I then make then one Graph?

Comment: You can use the `subcaption` package which introduces a subfigure environment.

Comment: To answer the question "how should I them make them one graph", a variation on `\includegraphics[width=5in]{plot1.pdf}\\
\includegraphics[width=5in]{plot2.pdf}\\
\includegraphics[width=5in]{plot3.pdf}` should suffice.  The other issue is whether your figure sizes are larger than the margin widths.  Without a full working example, it is hard to tell.

Comment: The minipages are useless. They don't do anything in your code. Simply add an empty line between the graphics or \\ to get them one under the other.

Comment: I have just removed the `minipage` and the result ist satisfactory. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comments above tell you what to do, the reason that what you did did not do anything is that you were centering the minipages but they were full width already so centering (or flush left or right) does nothing as a full width box is already "centred".

Within the minipage the settings are restored closer to default page settings, so if you want to centre the image inside a minipage the `\centering` command needs to be *inside* each `minipage`. But here, you can simply delete the minipages and allow the outer `\centering` to affect the included graphics directly.